# How to swap Fragment dynamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am little confuse How to use Fragments in Android apps!  I am beginner in android and I am trying to build an apps for tablet 7 Landscape as you seen in the image below!

A, B, D How to swap fragment! By click event. When user click on A the content of A moved and shows in D and content of D shows in A and so on.

I want to be able to swap the content of A,B,and D dynamically!

What I should use? Fragment, Fragment Activity.

For example if D showing Video in VideoView, then when user click on A I want D to show TextView or any kind of data (but is not video View)
as well as showing the Video in A.

```
<pre>
<!--> 
//////////////////////////////////////////// 
/ -------   -----------------------------  / 
/ -  A  -   -                           -  / 
/ -     -   -                           -  / 
/ -------   -                           -  /  
/ -  C  -   -            D              -  / 
/ -     -   -                           -  / 
/ -------   -                           -  / 
/ -  B  -   -                           -  / 
/ -     -   -                           -  / 
/ -------   -----------------------------  / 
//////////////////////////////////////////// 
<-->
</pre>
```

What I did is I made 4 fragment and put them inside the Main_Activity

fragment_A   I have problem with swap the content with D.

fragment_B   I have problem changing the content of D.

fragment_C   I connected with Fragment_C class that shows some static data.

fragment_D   I have problem with swap the content with A.

I am happy to for you suggestions!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and go check [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Check out replace / add / remove fragment methods. I'm sure you'll find what you are looking for.

ex :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and stuffs like :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(container, newFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Where `container` is a simple View (RelativeLayout or other things).

**EDIT :**

Example :

*main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_snapshots"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_snap1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_snap2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/big_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout specify, almost - except I only have 2 fragments on the left, what you are trying to do.

Then using `onClickListeners` and the function I gave you above, you might be able to do what you want.

Your containers will be the different IDs I put (big_fragment, fragment_snap1 & fragment_snap2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that was helpful! but I need an example to let me understand How I can connect the code together! How to define them in the activity_main and how to connect the empty container! with xml fill full of imagebutton and views as mixed with different controller!

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement listeners .. go through following link :-

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: This is not something that I think helps in answering the question, but I think it is good to know about this too.